# Avoid writing SAME string to a text file when updating python

Tags: python, string, file-io

I have a text file("Memory.txt") that contains the following string:

```
111111111
11111111
111111
1111111111
11111111111
111111111111111
1111111111111
```

I'm pretty new to python and also new here but I wonder if there is a way I can add another string(e.g '111111111111') to this same file (only if the string does not exist in the file).

My code is composed of two sections:

1. reads text file (e.g 'Memory.txt') and selects one of the string in the file
2. writes a new string to the same file (if the string does not exist in the file) but I've not been able to achieve this, below is my code for this section:

   ```
   with open("Memory.txt", "a+") as myfile:
       for lines in myfile.read().split():
           if 'target_string' == lines:
               continue
           else:
               lines.write('target_string')
   ```

This does not return/do anything, please could someone point in the right direction or explain to me what to do.

Thanks

Comment: I fixed the `'Memory.txt"` to `"Memory.txt"`. Make sure such a problem does not exist in your code (it is advisable to copy'and'paste to SO).

Comment: It should be `my_file.write` not `lines.write`.

Answer (score 3):

You can just do:

```
# Open for read+write
with open("Memory.txt", "r+") as myfile:

    # A file is an iterable of lines, so this will
    # check if any of the lines in myfile equals line+"\n"
    if line+"\n" not in myfile:

        # Write it; assumes file ends in "\n" already
        myfile.write(line+"\n")
```

`myfile.write(line+"\n")` can also be written as

```
# Python 3
print(line, file=myfile)

# Python 2
print >>myfile, line
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call "write" on the file object:

```
with open("Memory.txt", "a+") as myfile:
    for lines in myfile.read().split():
        if 'target_string' == lines:
            continue
        else:
            myfile.write('target_string')
```

Comment: @poke `elif` -> `else`

Comment: @yuxuan You can suggest that change yourself if you click the [edit] link.

Comment: @yuxuan Oh, fair point. Edited it for you, thanks for spotting the mistake!

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood what you want:

```
with open("Memory.txt", "r+") as myfile:
    if 'target_string' not in myfile.readlines():
        myfile.write('target_string')
```

- Open file
- Read all lines
- Check if target string in lines
- If no - append

Comment: This doesn't work, you want to use `"r+"` as the mode for `.readlines` to work. This requires that you can keep the whole file in memory (and you have to read the whole file); not calling `.readlines` avoids that, but then you have my version ;).

Comment: You are correct. And yeah, I think your treating file as iterable would be better in any case indeed :-/

Answer (score 0):

I would simply set a bool to True when found it, write in the end if not

```
with open("Memory.txt", "a+") as myfile:
    for lines in myfile.read().split():
        if 'target_string' == lines:
            fnd = True # you found it
            break
    if !fnd:
        myfile.write('target_string')
```